# how to save data to a text file on java without a dialog box pop up having the user click save

Tags: java

I'm trying to save data from a GUI I made, to a text document. In the GUI I have a menubar with a menu for opening and saving. they both work just fine. the problem is with the finish button. The finish button has to save to a text document without that popup box showing (without this
https://gyazo.com/41fd2370025c7c49cb375c0f64936597).

It has to save in the background without the user having to click "ok" or "save" in my case. It has to save automatically basically. Here is my code:

```
public class Survey extends JFrame {

    public JLabel label;
    public JLabel age;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JComboBox<String> majorsList;
    JTextField textField;
    JRadioButton Male;
    JRadioButton Female;
    JCheckBox workButton;
    JCheckBox homeButton;
    JCheckBox pcButton;
    Integer ageInfo;
    int hasJob;
    int isHome;
    int hasPC;
    int age1;
    int workAns;
    int homeAns;
    int PCAns;

    String majorsInfo;
    String rbinfoMale;
    String rbinfoFemale;
    String sex;
    File fileToSave;
    String file_name;
    String My_File;
    JPanel rButton;
    ButtonGroup bg1;
    JFileChooser fileChooser;
    File fileToOpen;
    StringBuilder sb;
    String fullcombo;
    JFrame parentFrame;
    JMenuItem openItem;
    JMenuItem saveItem;
    File file;
    ArrayList<String> allInputs = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Survey() {
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        //JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
        //textfield.add(textfield(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel finishButton = new JPanel();
        finishButton.add(finish());
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.add(age());
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.add(Majors());
        centerPanel.add(RadioButtons());
        centerPanel.add(locationWork());
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(createFileMenu());
        menuBar.add(createDrawMenu());
        //ageInput.add(createTextField());
        //createTextField();
        //textField = new JTextField(10);
        //textField.setBounds(5, 5, 280, 50);

        //panel.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(finishButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800, 600);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Survey c = new Survey();
        c.setTitle("Survey");
        c.setVisible(true);

    }

    public JMenu createFileMenu() {
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem quitItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        ActionListener listener = new ExitItemListener();
        quitItem.addActionListener(listener);
        ActionListener listener2 = new SaveItemListener();
        saveItem.addActionListener(listener2);
        ActionListener listener3 = new OpenItemListener();
        openItem.addActionListener(listener3);
        menu.add(saveItem);
        menu.add(openItem);
        menu.add(quitItem);
        return menu;
    }

    public JMenu createDrawMenu() {
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Draw");
        saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem quitItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        ActionListener listener = new ExitItemListener();
        quitItem.addActionListener(listener);
        ActionListener listener2 = new SaveItemListener();
        saveItem.addActionListener(listener2);
        menu.add(saveItem);
        menu.add(openItem);
        menu.add(quitItem);
        return menu;
    }

    public JPanel finish() {

        JButton finish = new JButton("Finish");
        panel.add(finish);
        ActionListener listener = new ExitItemListener();
        finish.addActionListener(listener);
        ActionListener listener2 = new SaveItemListener();
        finish.addActionListener(listener2);
        return panel;
    }

    public JPanel age() {
        JPanel textf = new JPanel();
        textf.add(age = new JLabel("Age: "));
        textField = new JTextField(10);
        textField.setBounds(5, 5, 280, 50);
        textField.setFont(textField.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
        textf.setBorder(new BevelBorder(0));
        textf.add(textField);
        return textf;
    }

    public JPanel Majors() {
        JPanel majorPanel = new JPanel();

        String[] majorsStrings = {"Biology", "Chemistry", "Computer Science", "Engineering"};
        majorsList = new JComboBox<String>(majorsStrings);
        majorsList.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "College"));
        majorsList.setSelectedIndex(3);
        majorsList.addActionListener(majorsList);

        majorPanel.add(majorsList);
        return majorPanel;

    }

    public JPanel RadioButtons() {

        bg1 = new ButtonGroup();
        rButton = new JPanel();
        Male = new JRadioButton("Male");
        Female = new JRadioButton("Female");
        rButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        bg1.add(Male);
        bg1.add(Female);
        rButton.add(Male);
        rButton.add(Female);

        return rButton;

    }

    public JPanel locationWork() {
        workButton = new JCheckBox("Work");
        homeButton = new JCheckBox("Have Children");
        pcButton = new JCheckBox("Own PC");
        JPanel cButton = new JPanel();
        workButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        homeButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_G);
        pcButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        cButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        cButton.add(workButton);
        cButton.add(homeButton);
        cButton.add(pcButton);
        return cButton;
    }

    private String inputCombo(int age1, String major, String sex, int work, int kids, int comp) {
        String newAge = Integer.toString(age1);
        String hasWork = Integer.toString(work);
        String hasKids = Integer.toString(kids);
        String hasComp = Integer.toString(comp);
        String combo = major + ", " + newAge + ", " + sex + ", " + hasWork + ", " + hasKids + ", " + hasComp;
        return combo;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> inputData() {
        boolean catcher = true;
        try {
            age1 = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
        } catch (IllegalFormatException ex) {
            catcher = false;
            System.out.println("Not an integer");
        }
        majorsInfo = majorsList.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (Male.isSelected()) {
            sex = "Male";
        } else if (Female.isSelected()) {
            sex = "Female";
        } else {
            sex = "";
            catcher = false;
        }
        if (workButton.isSelected()) {
            workAns = 1;
        } else {
            workAns = 0;
        }
        if (homeButton.isSelected()) {
            homeAns = 1;
        } else {
            homeAns = 0;
        }
        if (pcButton.isSelected()) {
            PCAns = 1;
        } else {
            PCAns = 0;
        }
        if (catcher) {
            fullcombo = inputCombo(age1, majorsInfo, sex, workAns, homeAns, PCAns);
            allInputs.add(fullcombo);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fill out all fields please");
        }
        return allInputs;
    }

    class ExitItemListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    class SaveItemListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event1) {

            try {

                fileChooser.showSaveDialog(Survey.this);

                if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(Survey.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);

                    for (String a : inputData()) {
                        sb.append(a);
                        sb.append("\r\n");
                    }
                    fw.write(sb.toString());
                    fw.flush();
                    fw.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
        }

    }

    class OpenItemListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event2) {

            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            fileChooser.showOpenDialog(Survey.this);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So remove the part of your code that shows a save dialog.  Do you understand what your code means?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever started a background thread that does the saving part in your code snippet, could you show us that part, and explain what is going wrong

Comment: Create a utility class which can perform the save action, or a `ActionListener`, without prompting the user. Use this when saving, when required, prompt the user first

Comment: @MadProgrammer thats what i've been trying to implement and I can't actually figure out how to..

Comment: Please consider posting [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).